# How to output Crystal reports to pdf without report viewer?

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports

I've looked everywhere for a tutorial to save a crystal report to harddrive as a pdf in c# without using report viewer but cannot find anything.

Can this be done and if so How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done.

Check out the [ExportToStream](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/CrystalReports_dotNET_SDK/crystalreports_net_doc/doc/crsdk_net_doc/html/crtsktutorialsrdexportingaddendumexporttostreamcall.htm) or [ExportToDisk](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/CrystalReports_dotNET_SDK/crystalreports_net_doc/doc/crsdk_net_doc/html/crtsktutorialsrdexportingaddendumexporttodisk.htm) methods on the ReportDocument

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate the ReportViewer and render the contents:

Here is one example: http://forums.asp.net/t/1556522.aspx

Comment: This link looks to be for ssrs and not applicable to crystal reports. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is specifically for Crystal Reports.